# How to add Hours to Date Hierarchy in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have managed to create another Hierarchy with year, month, day, and hour

but it does not work as I wanted

I created a table that has Days and hours and linked it to my table.

The "Go to the next level in the hierarchy" does not accumulate for that period

[image]

i mean in that case I should get January for all years but what I get is Jan 2017, Jan 2018, Jan 2019

it act exactly as "Expand all down" button

[image]

Is there any way I can simply add Hours to the Date hierarchy
[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of the data and the join between the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated "hour" column in the fact table, for example,

```
Hour = TIME( HOUR( [AVHandoverHour] ), 0, 0 )
```

And, add it to the visual axis.

[image]